# Why does componentDidMount fires in a HOC where as componentDidUpdate does not fire?

Tags: reactjs, react-hoc

I am following a reactjs tutorial on higher order components(HOC). I want a HOC to log props when props change.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function logProps(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log("Component was mounted");
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      console.log("Current props: ", this.props);
      console.log("Previous props: ", prevProps);
    }
    render() {
      // Wraps the input component in a container, without mutating it. Good!
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }
}

class CustomDivElement extends React.Component{
  render(){
  return <div>{this.props.text}</div>
  }
}

function App(props) {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const EnhancedComponent = logProps(CustomDivElement);
  return (
    <div tabIndex="0" className="App ui container">
      <input
      type="text"
      value={text}
      onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />
      <EnhancedComponent text={text} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

At first I thought it's because I am using a HOC. So I introduced another lifecycle method which is `componentDidMount` and it's firing. The `componentDidUpdate` is not firing, why is that?

Comment: I'll probably say crap as I'm learning React/JS too, but does const have a different signification inside of outside of a function (local/global const), like in C++? Would you try creating your EnhancedComponent outside the App() function? EDIT: aaaaand Denis bellow confirmed my thoughts ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you unmount the component on every render, the component doesn't get to `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle.

```
function App(props) {
  // Remount on every render
  const EnhancedComponent = logProps(CustomDivElement);
  ...
}
```

Instead, when using HOC, or any other Component, you want to mount it once:

```
// export default logProps(CustomDivElement)
const EnhancedComponent = logProps(CustomDivElement);

function App(props) {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  return (
    <div tabIndex="0" className="App ui container">
      <input
      type="text"
      value={text}
      onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />
      <EnhancedComponent text={text} />
    </div>
  )
}
```